# Compojure static resources work in dev but not prod

Tags: tomcat, clojure, war, compojure

I'm building a web app with Compojure 1.6.0.  For third-party JS libraries, I install them with npm, which puts them in a folder called `node_modules` (not customizable).  To serve them up, I did this:

```
(route/files "/node_modules" {:root "node_modules/"})
```

which works fine in development.  For production, I deploy an uberwar, so before creating the war I just copy these files into the public resources:

```
# deploy.sh
cp -r node_modules/ resources/public/node_modules/
lein ring uberwar
```

This all works fine.

Now I'd like to change my URI paths to say `/static/` instead of `/node_modules/`.  I tried changing my routing line to say:

```
(route/files "/static" {:root "node_modules/"})
```

and then updating all the HTML references that point to these URIs.  This works as expected in development (`lein ring server-headless`), but in production (deployed warfile) it fails.  My `route/not-found` handler is called for any path under `/static/`.

What gives?  Why does the URI path have anything to do with this, and only in one environment?

Comment: Oh, I might have found an explanation: `wrap-defaults` adds a `route/resources` automatically, so perhaps my dev env was picking up my `route/files`, and the prod env was using the automatic `route/resources` one.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `wrap-defaults` (which seems pretty much mandatory for any non-trivial webpage), and it adds `route/resources` by default.  That was a no-op in dev, but caused prod to look for `node_modules` by name.

That wasn't a problem, exactly, but it did hide the actual problem.  When I changed the `route/files` call, it changed the behavior of dev, but that wasn't being used in prod.

I don't know what the *correct* solution is, but for now I'm disabling `:static` in `wrap-defaults`, and making a matching pair of calls to `route/files` and `route/resources` myself, so I have full control over this.